# Add a class to a group of divs each time one reaches 150px from the top

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, addclass

I have a bunch of divs in my html page, they are all block elements (one on top of the other, no floating), and what I want is that every time one of these divs reaches 150px from the top of the window, it gets a class .active applied to it. All of these divs have the same class name, but they each have different IDs to differentiate them. So I need some jQuery code that can do this same process to each div without having to write the code out for each one.

Here's the html:

```
<div id="steps">
   <div class="step" id="step-1"></div>
   <div class="step" id="step-2"></div>
   <div class="step" id="step-3"></div>
   <div class="step" id="step-4"></div>
</div>
```

I have jquery that works, but it targets one ID, so I need it to be more dynamic so that it can target each one. There are only 4 steps in total.

```
var distance = $('#step-1').offset().top - 150,
$window = $(window);
$window.scroll(function() {
   if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
     $('#step-1').addClass('active');
     }
   });
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('.step').filter(function() {
         return scrolled >= $(this).offset().top-150;
    }).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Awesome, this one works. One thing I forgot to mention was that I don't need to remove the .active class. Once it has been applied, it's done. So I just removed the ".removeClass('active)" from your code. Other than that it works great!

Comment: @jkilp - no problem, removed the removeClass()

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but:

```
$window.scroll(function() {
  $('.step').each(function() {
    var distance = $(this).offset().top - 150;
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```